# Is there an Android port number registry?

Tags: android, sockets

Is there a specific Android port number registry, similar to the ones maintained by IANA and LANANA?
If so, how do you go about applying for an allocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a specific Android port number registry, similar to the ones maintained by IANA

No, because Android is an operating system, not an Internet.

> and LANANA?

Android runs a Linux kernel; some of LANANA will be relevant. There is no other registry.

Few Android applications should not opening server sockets, IMHO, where by "few" I mean "none that I ever want to install".